# How to find all words that end with a period?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file containing many words ending in a `.`, most of which are abbreviations, e.g.:

- etc.
- p.s.

How can I output a list which shows all of these words, only once?

- All of the words have a space before, so this space can be used to find the beginning of the word.
- None of the words appear at the beginning of the line.
- There are no sentences in the file, so the periods are all used in this manner.

Comment: Can the words be split over two or more lines?  Also, this has a homework smell..

Comment: No, none of the words are split over lines. It is not homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the ways to do it would be:

```
egrep -o '\b[^ ]+\.' < list_of_words | sort | uniq
```

Comment: would split `p.s.` from the OP's examples

Comment: The redirection isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU grep, take advantage of Perl-compatible regexes: `grep -Po '\S*\.(?=$|\s)'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
egrep -io ' [a-z.]+\.' input_file | sort -u
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also find the word that ends with period(.) using split() function as:

```
def find_words_with_period(text):
# Tokenize the text based on whitespace characters
  tokens = text.split()

# Filter the words ending with a period
  words_with_period = [word for word in tokens if word.endswith('.')]

  return words_with_period


text = input("enter the text you want to find period(.) of ")
result = find_words_with_period(text)
print(result)
```

Comment: This question was about using `sed` in Bash.  You answered with a Python solution.  From reading your answers, I'm getting the impression that you are simply copying and pasting questions into ChatGPT or another AI tool and pasting *part* of the answer back.  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.