# Find all alphanumerical strings before a period

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

How do I retrieve all strings between a non-alphanumerical or underscore and a period?  For instance, for the below string, get `[sources_1st,sources]`.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10596688/1032531 was a similar question, but doesn't seem to work for me.

```
<?php

function check($pattern,$str)
{
    echo($pattern.'<br>');
    preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches);
    echo('<pre>'.print_r($matches,1).'</pre>');    
}
$str='fullname("protocol",coalesce(sources_1st.protocol,sources.protocol))';
echo($str.'<hr>');

check('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/',$str);
check('/[\w]\..*$/',$str);
check('/[^\w]\..*$/',$str);
check('/\w\..*$/',$str);
check('/\w+(?=.*\.)$/',$str);
check('/\w+(?=.*\\.)$/',$str);
check('/\b[^ ]+\.$/',$str);
check('/\b[^ ]+\\.$/',$str);
check('/.*?(?=\.)$/',$str);
```

Output:

```
fullname("protocol",coalesce(sources_1st.protocol,sources.protocol))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/

Array
(
    [0] => protocol,sources.protocol))
)

/[\w]\..*$/

Array
(
    [0] => t.protocol,sources.protocol))
)

/[^\w]\..*$/

Array
(
)

/\w\..*$/

Array
(
    [0] => t.protocol,sources.protocol))
)

/\w+(?=.*\.)$/

Array
(
)

/\w+(?=.*\.)$/

Array
(
)

/\b[^ ]+\.$/

Array
(
)

/\b[^ ]+\.$/

Array
(
)

/.*?(?=\.)$/

Array
(
)
```

Comment: Could you please give us an example of what the input looks like and what the output should be?

Comment: @jrn  Input is `'fullname("protocol",coalesce(sources_1st.protocol,sources.protocol))'` and output is `['sources_1st','sources']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using below regex you are able to match word characters between a non-word character and a period:

```
\W\K\w+(?=\.)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/xerhEY/1)

Explanation:

1. `\W` match a non-word character
2. `\K` throw away previous match
3. `\w+(?=\.)` any word characters up to a period

PHP code:

```
preg_match_all('~\W\K\w+(?=\.)~', $str, $matches)
```

Comment: Thanks revo.  The previous match being the `\W` non-word character before each match?

Comment: Nice solution .